# Python C API: how to flush stdout and stderr?

Tags: python, python-c-api

When writing a Python extension with C code, one can print to the python standard output and standard error streams using functions `PySys_WriteStdout` and `PySys_WriteStderr`, which work similarly to C's `printf` (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sys.html).

But after printing something through those functions, how can I flush the corresponding output stream? E.g. like C's `fflush(stdout)` and `fflush(stderr)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things from what I remember based on the [`PySys_WriteStdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sys.html#c.PySys_WriteStdout) call which simply calls [`sysmodule.sys_write(_Py_Identifier *key, FILE *fp, const char *format, va_list va)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ae0a2b756255629140efcbe57fc2e714f0267aa3/Python/sysmodule.c#L3266):

- [unset the `sys.stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/5994041), thus you'll access the raw STDOUT, not just Python's wrapper and for that you should be able to use standard C flushing
- get the reference for `sys.stdout` and flush it directly

Optionally, just set [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) as env var, but it's not as flexible and isn't present by default in the system

For the `sys.stdout` flushing, you might also be able to utilize [`PySys_GetObject(const char *name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sys.html#c.PySys_GetObject) directly and then call the [`io.IOBase.flush()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) in the `sys.stdout` reference.

[`PySys_GetObject("__stdout__")`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f25f2e2e8c8e48490d22b0cdf67f575608701f6f/Python/pylifecycle.c#L2383) according to the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f25f2e2e8c8e48490d22b0cdf67f575608701f6f/Python/pylifecycle.c#L2383) in the [`pylifecycle.init_sys_streams(PyThreadState *tstate)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f25f2e2e8c8e48490d22b0cdf67f575608701f6f/Python/pylifecycle.c#L2335)

Or if you want to live dangerously, just pull the private API (`_PySys_GetObjectId(&PyId_stdout)`) to utilize the same way CPython does. It's defined [in `bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f25f2e2e8c8e48490d22b0cdf67f575608701f6f/Python/bltinmodule.c#L25) via [`_Py_IDENTIFIER(varname)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31ee985db86c1339d00bd0d3cc1712019460670a/Include/cpython/object.h#L46).

[Here is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f25f2e2e8c8e48490d22b0cdf67f575608701f6f/Python/pylifecycle.c#L1589) how CPython does the flushing via its `pylifecycle.flush_std_files()` function.